# Combine two tables with multiple granularity level

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables and I want to merge them.
Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/999d0

`Result` table is what I expect to get. Table `utm` is a source-main table and table `report` contains data for `utm` rows. What I need:

- Take **id** and **utm_** from `utm` table and add stats from table `report` with proper granulation.

*Example*

In table `utm` I've a row: `(24611609, 'myTarget', 'Media', 'Social', NULL, NULL)` and in table report I've 2 rows:

```
(24611609, '2022-08-01', 200, 150, 15, 'myTarget', 'Media', 'Social', 'premium', 'subcribe'),
(24611609, '2022-08-01', 25, 10, 1, 'myTarget', 'Media', 'Social', 'free', 'subcribe')
```

Common is: `'myTarget', 'Media', 'Social'`

Proper granularity level is `id, utm_campaign, utm_source, utm_medium`, so I need to SUM and GROUP two rows by these keys. So for this I need something like this:

```
SELECT 
utm.row_id AS id,
utm.utm_campaign,
utm.utm_source,
utm.utm_medium,
utm.utm_content,
utm.utm_term,
report.date_of_visit,
sum(report.sessions) as sessions,
sum(report.pageviews) as pageviews,
sum(report.bounces) as bounces
FROM utm
inner join report on utm.row_id = report.id and utm.utm_campaign = report.utm_campaign and utm.utm_source = report.utm_source and utm.utm_medium = report.utm_medium
group by utm.row_id,
utm.utm_campaign,
utm.utm_source,
utm.utm_medium,
utm.utm_content,
utm.utm_term,
report.date_of_visit
```

I don't know how to deal with all possible granularity combinations. My idea was just use diffrent JOINS variations and merge results with UNION like:

```
join on id, utm_campaign
union
...
join on id, utm_campaign, utm_medium
union
...
join on id, utm_campaign, utm_source
...
```

But it's really stupid, I should create > 1000 unions and joins.

Any tips?

Comment: Put some effort into your data sample. It will take you way far than those explanations,

Comment: I updated fiddle. Hope now it looks cleaner

Comment: The ID of the 3rd line in the report is still wrong

Comment: And you still didn't clarify what is a legit input. `(24611609, 'myTarget', 'Media', 'Social', NULL, NULL)` is a legit input. Is `(24611609, 'myTarget', 'Media', NULL, 'free', NULL)` also a legit input?

Comment: Yes, it's a legit input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enjoy

```
with 
r as
(
    select      id
               ,date_of_visit
               
               ,sum(sessions)               as sessions
               ,sum(pageviews)              as pageviews
               ,sum(bounces)                as bounce
               
               ,coalesce(utm_campaign ,'')  as utm_campaign 
               ,coalesce(utm_source   ,'')  as utm_source 
               ,coalesce(utm_medium   ,'')  as utm_medium 
               ,coalesce(utm_content  ,'')  as utm_content
               ,coalesce(utm_term     ,'')  as utm_term   
             
    from        report as r

    group by    id
               ,date_of_visit
               ,cube(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

)         
select  r.*

from            r 

        join    utm as u 
        
        on      r.id = u.row_id
        
            and (r.utm_campaign, r.utm_source, r.utm_medium, r.utm_content, r.utm_term)
                is not distinct from 
                (u.utm_campaign, u.utm_source, u.utm_medium, u.utm_content, u.utm_term)
   
where   'NA' in (r.utm_campaign, r.utm_source, r.utm_medium, r.utm_content, r.utm_term) is not true
```

| id | date_of_visit | sessions | pageviews | bounce | utm_campaign | utm_source | utm_medium | utm_content | utm_term |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28573041 | 2022-08-01 | 1000 | 900 | 10 | Beeline_uppers_2022 | Null | Null | Null | Null |
| 24611609 | 2022-08-01 | 225 | 160 | 16 | myTarget | Media | Social | Null | Null |
| 28573041 | 2022-08-01 | 900 | 885 | 34 | shop_ smartfony | my_beeline | banner | Null | Null |
| 24611609 | 2022-08-01 | 1 | 1 | 0 | campaign | source | medium | content | term |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=38602dbea183f6aa450d985acf448ea8&hide=1)

Comment: See updated answer. Made it a little bit more fun.

Comment: And a little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

A more strightforward solution :-)

```
select      u.row_id
           ,r.date_of_visit
           
           ,sum(r.sessions)     as sessions
           ,sum(r.pageviews)    as pageviews
           ,sum(r.bounces)      as bounce
           
           ,u.utm_campaign
           ,u.utm_source  
           ,u.utm_medium  
           ,u.utm_content 
           ,u.utm_term    
         
from                utm     as u
            join    report  as r
            on       u.row_id = r.id
                and (u.utm_campaign = r.utm_campaign or u.utm_campaign is null)
                and (u.utm_source   = r.utm_source   or u.utm_source   is null)
                and (u.utm_medium   = r.utm_medium   or u.utm_medium   is null)
                and (u.utm_content  = r.utm_content  or u.utm_content  is null)
                and (u.utm_term     = r.utm_term     or u.utm_term     is null)
                                   
group by    u.row_id
           ,r.date_of_visit
           ,u.utm_campaign
           ,u.utm_source  
           ,u.utm_medium  
           ,u.utm_content 
           ,u.utm_term
```

| row_id | date_of_visit | sessions | pageviews | bounce | utm_campaign | utm_source | utm_medium | utm_content | utm_term |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24611609 | 2022-08-01 | 1 | 1 | 0 | campaign | source | medium | content | term |
| 24611609 | 2022-08-01 | 225 | 160 | 16 | myTarget | Media | Social | null | null |
| 28573041 | 2022-08-01 | 1000 | 900 | 10 | Beeline_uppers_2022 | null | null | null | null |
| 28573041 | 2022-08-01 | 900 | 885 | 34 | shop_ smartfony | my_beeline | banner | null | null |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=710b74f51640ff760451aa06498b2b28&hide=1)